# Is there any way to fetch and build a docker image during the Yocto build?

Tags: docker, embedded-linux, yocto

Would I have to call docker from an external toolchain? Is there any support for this operation? I wish I could write a recipe fetching, creating the docker image and putting it in the root filesystem for later execution but I'm not really sure where to begin.

I appreciate any input.

Comment: Yes, just call Docker from an external toolchain, e.g. CI/CD.